# Is it possible to open a links in a new window in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to open google and youtube in one click. But the tricky part here is, I want it to be open in a new window. I already achieved it on tab. But my client don't want to open in tab. So I need to change it on new window.

Here's what I've tried so far.

```
<a href="#" id="linkTrigger">Open Links</a>

var trigger = document.getElementById('linkTrigger'),
    link = ['www.google.com', 'www.youtube.com'];

trigger.onclick = function {
    [].forEach.call(link, function(e){
        if(e == 'www.google.com')
            window.open(e, 'newwindow', 'height: 100px, width: 100px');
        else 
            window.open(e);
    });
}
```

I also read that window.open(/* link */, _blank) should open in a new window, However, for me. It's opening in new tab. I'm currently using Google Chrome 49.

The script can just open google as we expected.

I searched for possible solutions but there's no the same problem with me.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You just want to open 2 links right?

Comment: @grec0o Yes, but in a new window.

Comment: @Archer _"You can't force a new window to open any more"_ http://plnkr.co/edit/IXoDCXIF26gjPEUHSfDc?p=preview

Comment: @guest271314 Deleted - I take that back.  I wasn't aware of that method.  I do hope it gets fixed at some point though!

Answer (score -1):

Use `"_blank"` as first parameter to `window.open()`, `"width=/*height*/,height=/*width*/"` as third parameter, then setting `location.href` of opened window

```
var w = window.open("_blank", "w", "width=600, height=400"); 
w.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

Comment: @HermLuna Try `window.open("/path/to/resource", "_blank", "width=100")`

Comment: I tried it but the problem is youtube is opening in the main tab.

Comment: It just open abc.text in new tab.

Comment: Try `window.open("_blank", "", "width=100, height=100")` at `console`; plnkr may have issues. If you save a reference to the window you can then set the `location.href` of the newly opened window

Comment: E.g., `var w = window.open("_blank", "", "width=100, height=100"); w.location.href = "http://www.google.com"`

Answer (score -1):

there is a full topic about how to do it and what problems with opening urls in new tabs are.

Here is the link:
[Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window) using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript)

hope this helps,
Regards

Comment: This won't help to me because I have a lot of triggers. For example, They want to open google and facebook or facebook and youtube in new tab. Thanks anyway for response.

Comment: Creating hidden links and triggering them on you'r triggers wont do the job?

Comment: No. It can't. What I want is a fresh window with the tabs over there.